# set zk default direction rtl

Tags: jakarta-ee, right-to-left, zk

I am Iranian developer, because of Persian language is RTL; I need to set default zk direction to rtl.

All of pages and behaviors such as message boxes , popups and so on.

I am using RTL CSS for my `<window>` tags in .zul files, but how other behaviors can be handled?

Is there any systemic plug in ZK for handling this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is, to [add a css to the default theme](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/Customizing_Standard_Themes#Add_Additional_CSS)
that define all input types to be rtl.
The component pages from the style guide should help
to find all input elements

Comment: my problem resolved by adding this css: `*{direction: rtl;}` in my default theme css. thanks for your quick response.